# JavaScript praseInt("3e3", 10) gives answer 3

Tags: javascript, loops

My task to prompt for a number. And loop till its a number

```
do {
    num=prompt ("Please enter a number:");
    if (parseInt(num,10)) {  
        if (typeof num !=="number") {
            if (!isNaN(num)) {  
                stop=1;
            }
        }
    }
} while (stop != 1);
```

When I enter "3e3" it works. Y?
how do i fix the praseInt("3e3", 10)?

Comment: `3e3` is not an `int`, it's a `float`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: I believe he wants the `3e3` to be detected as a non-number.

Comment: @Amadan, you're probably right. None of the `parse*()` functions will work, then.

Comment: The string starts with a number, so it's valid to parse it. How do you want it fixed? What should happen if you enter `3e3`?

Comment: @Guffa: Going on a hunch by the OP code, but probably stop.

Comment: How about a `+num|0` to make `3e3` into `3000`?

Comment: Use parseFlaot instead if you want to parse floats.

Answer (score 3):

Check it with regular expression such as `/^\d+$/`.

```
if (/^\d+$/.test(num)) {
  // it's an integer
} else {
  // it's not an integer
}
```

Comment: I am new to Javascript only (1 day) lol.. How do i use this function?

Answer (score 2):

`parseInt` will take the first characters of the string until it finds one that it's numeric (or reaches the end).

With that in mind, `3e3` reads the first `3` and discards the rest.

That said, your logic is flawed: `parseInt` *returns* the number, whereas you seem to be treating it like it were changing it.

Answer (score 1):

That's because [parseInt ignores anything after (and including) first invalid character](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.2) (step 11.)

If you want to reject things like `3e3`, then you can simply test whether the string contains decimals only by doing `/^\s*\d+\s*$/.test(num)`.

If you want to process things like `3e3`, then you can simply use unary + operator [to convert a string to a number](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3), something like `+num`. (This will accept strings like `4.2e+42` or `0x2A`.)